# SELECT most recent in Oracle SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Good morning,

I am trying to accomplish something that is a bit above my level of expertise. Thanks to some folks on this site, my Oracle-SQL skills have increased tremendously, but I want to take a stab at something new.

I have four tables - a table of Purchase Orders, a table of Product Vendors, a table of Defects, and a table of Parts.

My company has three "divisions" (Demolition (A), Concrete (B), and Construction (C)). I want to look at all DEFECTS against the PARTS purchased for a specific division. I have a working query below. My issue is that we sometimes have multiple POs FOR THE SAME PART - sometimes we switch vendors for whatever reason (that is on the logistics team, not me ;)) so I will end up with something that looks like this:

[image]

Notice there are two rows, different vendors, but everything else the same. I only want THE MOST RECENTLY PURCHASED PART. There is a Purchase Order Date I am filtering on. Here is the query:

```
WITH

    PartNums AS -- Grabs me all of the stuff we "bought", and its vendor, in the construction division since Jan 1 2018
        (
            SELECT 
                PO_ITEM AS "PART_NUM",
                VEND_NUM,
                VEND_NM,
                PODiv AS "DIVISION_CD"
            FROM
                tblPurchases
                    INNER JOIN tblVendors ON tblPurchased.VEND_NUM = tblVendors.VEND_NUM
            WHERE
                PODate >= '01-Jan-2018'
                AND
                PODiv = 'C'
        ),

    Defects AS -- Grabs me the listed defects against their stuff
        (
            SELECT 
                PartNums.*,
                DEFECT_NUM,
                DEFECT_CAT
            FROM
                PartNums
                    INNER JOIN tblDefects ON PartNums.PART_NUM = tblDefects.DEFECTIVE_PART_NUM

        ),

    Names AS -- Grabs me the name of the part we are buying
        (
            SELECT
                Defects.*,
                PART_NM
            FROM
                Defects
                    INNER JOIN tblParts ON Defects.PART_NUM = tblParts.PART_NUM
        )

    SELECT
        VEND_NUM,
        VEND_NM,
        PART_NUM,
        PART_NM,
        DEFECT_NUM,
        DEFECT_CAT,
        DIVISION_CD

    FROM Names
```

Essentially, what I would like to do is in the event there are multiple vendors for singular part number, just grab the most recent...does anyone know how to do that? I tried SELECT DISTINCT but it made no difference... :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a formatted comment.  To get the most recent something, you need to use a subquery somewhere.

```
where yourDate = (subquery to find more recent date)
```

or

```
from yourTable join (
subquery to get most recent date
plus a recordId
) temp on yourTable.recordID = temp.recordID
and yourTable.yourDate = temp.mostRecentDate
```

The details are up to you.

Comment: Hi @Dan Bracuk, thanks a lot for your reply. I think my issue is I don't know how to find the most recent date? I have tried an ORDER BY and then a MAX, but I only got ONE result (the overall most recent, not just the most recent of each distinct part number). 

Sorry for the confusion, but I appreciate your help!

Comment: Do one thing at a time.  Start with a query that gets you the most recent date for each part.  Then turn it into a subquery and use it with the real tables.

Comment: I'm sorry for being so dense, but that is what I don't understand - I don't think I know how to find "the most recent date for each part". I tried using MAX() on the date, but then I only got one result, not one result for each part.

Comment: Did your effort include a part identifier in your select and group by clauses?

Answer (score 0):

Use an analytic function like rank() to order the dates within a group.

Rank() over (partition by grouping_column order by ordering_column desc) as my_rank

Then, in the outer query get only the top ranked value

Where my_rank = 1

Sorry this is not formatted, but first time answering via my mobile.

Comment: Hi @unleashed, thanks a lot for your suggestion. Would this be doable for every "part number"?

Comment: My issue is that I get multiple vendors (off of the purchase orders) for the same part. I am hoping to just get one row, with the most recent vendor, for an individual part.

Comment: Stack Overflowing with a mobile?  Well aren't you a glutton for punishment?

Comment: you can use the rank() over (partition by partnum, partname, defectnum,defectcategory, division order by purchase_order_Date desc) rank and use an outer query with rank = 1