# Oracle SQL Selecting Most Recent Data

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Good morning,

This is a follow-up to [SELECT most recent in Oracle SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808373/select-most-recent-in-oracle-sql-query)

I am hoping to take my Oracle skills to the next level after learning a lot from this site.

I work for a small construction company and thus, we buy a lot of smaller parts/materials from our vendors. Sometimes, in the same calendar year, we may switch who we buy the SAME part from. I want to only grab the most recent VENDOR for each individual PART NUMBER. Here is an example of what I mean:
The code for my starting query:

```
WITH

PartNums AS -- Grabs me all of the stuff we "bought", and its vendor, in the construction division since Jan 1 2018
    (
        SELECT 
            PO_ITEM AS "PART_NUM",
            VEND_NUM,
            VEND_NM,
            PODiv AS "DIVISION_CD"
        FROM
                INNER JOIN 
                    (
                        SELECT MAX(PODate) OVER(PARTITION BY PO_Number, VEND_NUM))
                        FROM tblPurchases
                        WHERE PODate > '01-Jan-2017'
                    ) tblTemp INNER JOIN tblPurchases ON tblPurchases.VEND_NUM = tblTemp.VEND_NUM
                INNER JOIN tblVendors ON tblPurchases.VEND_NUM = tblVendors.VEND_NUM
        WHERE
            PODate > '01-Jan-2017'
            AND
            PODiv = 'C'
    ),

Defects AS -- Grabs me the listed defects against their stuff
    (
        SELECT 
            PartNums.*,
            DEFECT_NUM,
            DEFECT_CAT
        FROM
            PartNums
                INNER JOIN tblDefects ON PartNums.PART_NUM = tblDefects.DEFECTIVE_PART_NUM

        WHERE
            DEFECT_DATE > '01-Jan-2017'

    ),

Names AS
    (
        SELECT
            Defects.*,
            PART_NM
        FROM
            Defects
                INNER JOIN tblParts ON Defects.PART_NUM = tblParts.PART_NUM
    )

SELECT
    VEND_NUM,
    VEND_NM,
    PART_NUM,
    PART_NM,
    DEFECT_NUM,
    DEFECT_CAT,
    DIVISION_CD

FROM Names
```

This produces the following results:

```
| Vendor Number | Vendor Name                  | Part Number | Part Name      | Defect Number | Defect Category | Division | Purchase Order Date |
|---------------|------------------------------|-------------|----------------|---------------|-----------------|----------|---------------------|
| 200123        | Push-Button LLC              | 54211EW     | Faceplate      | PROB333211    | WRPT            | C        | 11-Jan-2017         |
| 200587        | Entirely Concrete            | 69474TR     | 2in Screw      | PROB587412    | WRPT            | C        | 03-Mar-2017         |
| 200444        | Maaco                        | 77489GF     | Hammer NR      | PROB369854    | WRPT            | C        | 08-Aug-2017         |
| 200100        | Fleischman Contractors       | 21110LW     | Service        | PROB215007    | OPYM            | C        | 01-Jun-2017         |
| 200664        | Advanced Tool Repair LLC     | 47219UZ     | Service        | PROB9874579   | UPYM            | C        | 14-Jan-2018         |
| 200999        | AllTech Electronic Equipment | 36654DD     | Plastic Casing | PROB326598    | NA              | C        | 16-Jan-2018         |
| 200321        | ZyotoCard Electronics        | 74200ZN     | Service        | PROB012547    | MISCT           | C        | 19-Apr-2017         |
| 200331        | Black&Decker                 | 41122UT     | .11mm Drillbit | PROB147741    | BRKN            | C        | 03-Aug-2017         |
| 200333        | Sears                        | 41122UT     | .11mm Drillbit | PROB147741    | BRKN            | C        | 11-Mar-2017         |
```

**As you can see, there are 2 vendors for Part Number 41122UT. For this part number, I only want Black & Decker (whose PO Date is 5 months newer than Sears).**

I would like for the data to look like this:

```
| Vendor Number | Vendor Name                  | Part Number | Part Name      | Defect Number | Defect Category | Division | Purchase Order Date |
|---------------|------------------------------|-------------|----------------|---------------|-----------------|----------|---------------------|
| 200123        | Push-Button LLC              | 54211EW     | Faceplate      | PROB333211    | WRPT            | C        | 11-Jan-2017         |
| 200587        | Entirely Concrete            | 69474TR     | 2in Screw      | PROB587412    | WRPT            | C        | 03-Mar-2017         |
| 200444        | Maaco                        | 77489GF     | Hammer NR      | PROB369854    | WRPT            | C        | 08-Aug-2017         |
| 200100        | Fleischman Contractors       | 21110LW     | Service        | PROB215007    | OPYM            | C        | 01-Jun-2017         |
| 200664        | Advanced Tool Repair LLC     | 47219UZ     | Service        | PROB9874579   | UPYM            | C        | 14-Jan-2018         |
| 200999        | AllTech Electronic Equipment | 36654DD     | Plastic Casing | PROB326598    | NA              | C        | 16-Jan-2018         |
| 200321        | ZyotoCard Electronics        | 74200ZN     | Service        | PROB012547    | MISCT           | C        | 19-Apr-2017         |
| 200331        | Black&Decker                 | 41122UT     | .11mm Drillbit | PROB147741    | BRKN            | C        | 03-Aug-2017         |
```

I have found that using MAX() OVER (PARTITION BY) can be used to return the most recent, so I tried this query and it now runs, but it gives me the most recent date, for each vendor, for each part. Not just for each part. I need the MOST RECENT VENDOR INFORMATION (found on the Purchase Order, so ultimately need the most recent Purchase Order) for every PART. Could anyone advise?

WITH

```
PartNums AS -- Grabs me all of the stuff we "bought", and its vendor, in the construction division since Jan 1 2018
    (
        SELECT 
            PO_ITEM AS "PART_NUM",
            VEND_NUM,
            VEND_NM,
            PODiv AS "DIVISION_CD"
        FROM
                INNER JOIN 
                    (
                        SELECT PO_NUMBER, VEND_NUM, MAX(PODate) OVER(PARTITION BY PO_NUMBER, VEND_NUM))
                        FROM tblPurchases
                        WHERE PODate > '01-Jan-2017'
                    ) tblTemp INNER JOIN tblPurchases ON tblPurchases.VEND_NUM = tblTemp.VEND_NUM
                INNER JOIN tblVendors ON tblPurchases.VEND_NUM = tblVendors.VEND_NUM
        WHERE
            PODate > '01-Jan-2017'
            AND
            PODiv = 'C'
    ),

Defects AS -- Grabs me the listed defects against their stuff
    (
        SELECT 
            PartNums.*,
            DEFECT_NUM,
            DEFECT_CAT
        FROM
            PartNums
                INNER JOIN tblDefects ON PartNums.PART_NUM = tblDefects.DEFECTIVE_PART_NUM

        WHERE
            DEFECT_DATE > '01-Jan-2017'

    ),

Names AS
    (
        SELECT
            Defects.*,
            PART_NM
        FROM
            Defects
                INNER JOIN tblParts ON Defects.PART_NUM = tblParts.PART_NUM
    )

SELECT
    VEND_NUM,
    VEND_NM,
    PART_NUM,
    PART_NM,
    DEFECT_NUM,
    DEFECT_CAT,
    DIVISION_CD

FROM Names
```

Thank you very much for your time and help. Sorry if this creates any ambiguity.

Comment: Please include structure and sample data for both tables, and expected output - [as text not images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). The `MAX(PODate OVER(PARTITION BY PO_Number))` should be `MAX(PODate) OVER(PARTITION BY PO_Number)`, but doesn't give the error you mention...

Comment: @AlexPoole Frankly, I'm really horrible at getting a table to format. Do you have advice on how I can get better at that?

Comment: @AlexPoole I'll look more into getting table structures, sorry about that. I just updated the code, and am getting "tblTemp.VEND_NUM invalid identifier

Comment: Your inline view doesn't have `VEND_NUM` in its select list. It will be easier to answer with structures and data; not sure what you mean about formatting, you can [format it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) the same way as the code. Simplest thing is to describe and query the data from something like a SQL Developer worksheet (not result grid) and just copy and paste. (But minimal data to show what you're doing...)

Comment: @AlexPoole I just updated it...hopefully this makes it easier for experts to help me. Is there any way I can "bump" my post now that it is formatted differently?

Comment: I find this strange. You look for parts that are reported defective and show their latest order. Does this make sense? If a part was reported defective five years ago, why would you look for the most recent order? Shouldn't you be looking for the last order before the defect? Does your `tblDefects` have a date?

Comment: Yes, tblDefects has a "DEFECT_DATE" column which I would filter on by the same date. I forgot to include that in my original post.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner My main problem is, is that my MAX() OVER (PARTITION BY) function isn't working properly.

Comment: Okay, what Oracle version are you using?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I believe it is: Oracle DB 12C, 64-Bit. If you'd like, we can move to [chat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using MAX, use DENSE_RANK, RANK or ROW_NUMBER and partition it by PO_NUMBER, VEND_NUM, order it by PO_DATE DESC, and filter out the records that returns value greater than 1,

Your query could be similar like below, as you can see I used DENSE_RANK,

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT A.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY PO_NUMBER, VEND_NUM ORDER BY podate DESC) rank_value 
          FROM your_table)
  WHERE rank_value = 1;
```

Comment: This was great. I just wanted to take a minute to say @eifla001 thank you

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly you are looking for all parts reported defective since a particular date and want to find the according order so as to be able to contact the supplier.

In Oracle 12c you can use `CROSS APPLY` to join only the latest order (which you get with `ORDER BY date DESC FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`).

```
select
  o.vend_num as vendor_number,
  o.vend_nm as vendor_name,
  d.defective_part_num as part_number,
  p.part_nm as part_name,
  d.defect_num as defect_number,
  d.defect_cat as defect_category,
  o.podiv as division,
  o.podate as purchase_order_date
from tbldefects d
cross apply
(
  select *
  from tblpurchases pu
  where pu.po_number = d.defective_part_num
    and pu.podate <= d.defect_date
    and pu.podiv = 'C'
  order by pu.podate desc
  fetch first row only
) o
join tblparts p on p.part_num = d.defective_part_num
where d.defect_date >= date '2017-01-01';
```

Comment: thank you for writing this up for me, I have never heard of cross apply nor of the ORDER BY date DESC FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY method. If you have a moment to chat, or are interested in assisting further, I would like to ask you a few questions. I must've ambiguously worded my question because I'm not sure this achieves what I'm looking for. Thank you very much!!